# What is a good way to store AWS credentials for test environment?

Tags: ruby, rspec, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

What is a good way to save AWS credentials for a ***testing*** environment? ENV vars work well in deployments, but I don't want to set up the ENV to run tests, and don't want to store credentials in the code.

Is there a good way to manage this?

Working in Ruby and RSpec.

EDIT: Tests run against AWS using VCR.

Comment: Are your tests running against AWS? Otherwise fake credentials are sufficient that you can add to your repos without worrying about.

Comment: Yes, the idea is to use VCR.

Answer (score 2):

A common approach is to store credentials in a yaml file (same way as database.yml) and load it in the testing environment. Then ignore this file in git.

That way you can ensure aws credentials are distributed separately from your source code.